# Configure WinRM to Use HTTPS makecert.exe Name Syntax

Tags: vmware, powershell, ssl-certificate

I am trying to enable the remote execution of powershell scripts on a remote server over https using [this](http://pubs.vmware.com/orchestrator-plugins/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.using.powershell.plugin.doc_10/GUID-2F7DA33F-E427-4B22-8946-03793C05A097.html) example.

What I do not understand is what value to give for the hostname when generating the cert. Is it the computer name or is it a url?

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to is a basic outline of how to make a cert request with `makecert.exe`.  I believe your specific question is in relation to the `-n` switch in the example for designating a name.  `makecert.exe` is expecting an `x.500` standard entry so you want to provide it a Distinguished Name (DN).

Some folx aren't familiar with Distinguished Names, so let me provide an example of one.  If you had an FQDN of `server1.fabrikam.corp` then your DN would be:

```
CN=server1,DC=fabrikam,DC=corp
```

In the case of the example you linked to, they're telling you to use CN and O to provide a DN.  Using the same FQDN example above, the entry would be:

```
CN=server1,O=fabrikam
```